# How can I find coordinates of centroid, orthocenter and center of out circle of the list of triangles?

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

I have a list of vertices of triangles

```
{{2, 3, 5},  {1, -7, -12},  {12, 4, 10}}, { {2, 3, 6},  {1, -7, -11},  {12, 4, 11}}, { {2, 3, 8},  {1, -7, -9},  {12, 4, 13}}, { {2, 3, 9},  {1, -7, -8},  {12, 4, 14}}, { {2, 4, 3},  {1, -6, -14},  {12, 5, 8}}, { {2, 4, 6},  {1, -6, -11},  {12, 5, 11}}, { {2, 4, 8},  {1, -6, -9},  {12, 5, 13}}, { {2, 4, 9},  {1, -6, -8},  {12, 5, 14}}, { {2, 5, 3},  {1, -5, -14},  {12, 6, 8}}, { {2, 5, 4},  {1, -5, -13},  {12, 6, 9}}, { {2, 5, 8},  {1, -5, -9},  {12, 6, 13}}, { {2, 5, 9},  {1, -5, -8},  {12, 6, 14}}, { {2, 6, 3},  {1, -4, -14},  {12, 7, 8}}, { {2, 6, 4},  {1, -4, -13},  {12, 7, 9}}, { {2, 6, 5},  {1, -4, -12},  {12, 7, 10}}, { {2, 6, 8},  {1, -4, -9},  {12, 7, 13}}, { {2, 6, 9},  {1, -4, -8},  {12, 7, 14}}, { {2, 7, 4},  {1, -3, -13},  {12, 8, 9}}, { {2, 7, 5},  {1, -3, -12},  {12, 8, 10}}, { {2, 7, 6},  {1, -3, -11},  {12, 8, 11}}, { {2, 7, 9},  {1, -3, -8},  {12, 8, 14}}, { {2, 8, 5},  {1, -2, -12},  {12, 9, 10}}, { {2, 8, 6},  {1, -2, -11},  {12, 9, 11}}, { {2, 9, 3},  {1, -1, -14},  {12, 10, 8}}, { {2, 9, 6},  {1, -1, -11},  {12, 10, 11}}, { {2, 9, 8},  {1, -1, -9},  {12, 10, 13}}, { {3, 4, 1},  {2, -6, -16},  {13, 5, 6}}, { {3, 4, 6},  {2, -6, -11},  {13, 5, 11}}, { {3, 4, 7},  {2, -6, -10},  {13, 5, 12}}, { {3, 4, 9},  {2, -6, -8},  {13, 5, 14}}, { {3, 5, 4},  {2, -5, -13},  {13, 6, 9}}, { {3, 5, 7},  {2, -5, -10},  {13, 6, 12}}, { {3, 5, 9},  {2, -5, -8},  {13, 6, 14}}, { {3, 6, 4},  {2, -4, -13},  {13, 7, 9}}, { {3, 6, 5},  {2, -4, -12},  {13, 7, 10}}, { {3, 6, 9},  {2, -4, -8},  {13, 7, 14}}, { {3, 7, 1},  {2, -3, -16},  {13, 8, 6}}, { {3, 7, 4},  {2, -3, -13},  {13, 8, 9}}, { {3, 7, 5},  {2, -3, -12},  {13, 8, 10}}, { {3, 7, 6},  {2, -3, -11},  {13, 8, 11}}, { {3, 7, 9},  {2, -3, -8},  {13, 8, 14}}, { {3, 8, 1},  {2, -2, -16},  {13, 9, 6}}, { {3, 8, 5},  {2, -2, -12},  {13, 9, 10}}, { {3, 8, 6},  {2, -2, -11},  {13, 9, 11}}, { {3, 8, 7},  {2, -2, -10},  {13, 9, 12}}, { {3, 9, 1},  {2, -1, -16},  {13, 10, 6}}, { {3, 9, 6},  {2, -1, -11},  {13, 10, 11}}, { {3, 9, 7},  {2, -1, -10},  {13, 10, 12}}, { {4, 1, 5},  {3, -9, -12},  {14, 2, 10}}, { {4, 1, 6},  {3, -9, -11},  {14, 2, 11}}, { {4, 1, 7},  {3, -9, -10},  {14, 2, 12}}, { {4, 5, 2},  {3, -5, -15},  {14, 6, 7}}, { {4, 5, 7},  {3, -5, -10},  {14, 6, 12}}, { {4, 5, 8},  {3, -5, -9},  {14, 6, 13}}, { {4, 6, 5},  {3, -4, -12},  {14, 7, 10}}, { {4, 6, 8},  {3, -4, -9},  {14, 7, 13}}, { {4, 7, 1},  {3, -3, -16},  {14, 8, 6}}, { {4, 7, 5},  {3, -3, -12},  {14, 8, 10}}, { {4, 7, 6},  {3, -3, -11},  {14, 8, 11}}, { {4, 8, 1},  {3, -2, -16},  {14, 9, 6}}, { {4, 8, 2},  {3, -2, -15},  {14, 9, 7}}, { {4, 8, 5},  {3, -2, -12},  {14, 9, 10}}, { {4, 8, 6},  {3, -2, -11},  {14, 9, 11}}, { {4, 8, 7},  {3, -2, -10},  {14, 9, 12}}, { {4, 9, 1},  {3, -1, -16},  {14, 10, 6}}, { {4, 9, 2},  {3, -1, -15},  {14, 10, 7}}, { {4, 9, 6},  {3, -1, -11},  {14, 10, 11}}, { {4, 9, 7},  {3, -1, -10},  {14, 10, 12}}, { {4, 9, 8},  {3, -1, -9},  {14, 10, 13}}, { {5, 1, 3},  {4, -9, -14},  {15, 2, 8}}, { {5, 1, 6},  {4, -9, -11},  {15, 2, 11}}, { {5, 1, 7},  {4, -9, -10},  {15, 2, 12}}, { {5, 1, 9},  {4, -9, -8},  {15, 2, 14}}, { {5, 2, 1},  {4, -8, -16},  {15, 3, 6}}, { {5, 2, 6},  {4, -8, -11},  {15, 3, 11}}, { {5, 2, 7},  {4, -8, -10},  {15, 3, 12}}, { {5, 2, 8},  {4, -8, -9},  {15, 3, 13}}, { {5, 6, 3},  {4, -4, -14},  {15, 7, 8}}, { {5, 6, 8},  {4, -4, -9},  {15, 7, 13}}, { {5, 6, 9},  {4, -4, -8},  {15, 7, 14}}, { {5, 7, 1},  {4, -3, -16},  {15, 8, 6}}, { {5, 7, 6},  {4, -3, -11},  {15, 8, 11}}, { {5, 7, 9},  {4, -3, -8},  {15, 8, 14}}, { {5, 8, 1},  {4, -2, -16},  {15, 9, 6}}, { {5, 8, 2},  {4, -2, -15},  {15, 9, 7}}, { {5, 8, 6},  {4, -2, -11},  {15, 9, 11}}, { {5, 8, 7},  {4, -2, -10},  {15, 9, 12}}, { {5, 9, 1},  {4, -1, -16},  {15, 10, 6}}, { {5, 9, 2},  {4, -1, -15},  {15, 10, 7}}, { {5, 9, 3},  {4, -1, -14},  {15, 10, 8}}, { {5, 9, 6},  {4, -1, -11},  {15, 10, 11}}, { {5, 9, 7},  {4, -1, -10},  {15, 10, 12}}, { {5, 9, 8},  {4, -1, -9},  {15, 10, 13}}, { {6, 1, 3},  {5, -9, -14},  {16, 2, 8}}, { {6, 1, 4},  {5, -9, -13},  {16, 2, 9}}, { {6, 1, 7},  {5, -9, -10},  {16, 2, 12}}, { {6, 1, 9},  {5, -9, -8},  {16, 2, 14}}, { {6, 2, 4},  {5, -8, -13},  {16, 3, 9}}, { {6, 2, 7},  {5, -8, -10},  {16, 3, 12}}, { {6, 2, 8},  {5, -8, -9},  {16, 3, 13}}, { {6, 3, 2},  {5, -7, -15},  {16, 4, 7}}, { {6, 3, 7},  {5, -7, -10},  {16, 4, 12}}, { {6, 3, 8},  {5, -7, -9},  {16, 4, 13}}, { {6, 3, 9},  {5, -7, -8},  {16, 4, 14}}, { {6, 7, 4},  {5, -3, -13},  {16, 8, 9}}, { {6, 7, 9},  {5, -3, -8},  {16, 8, 14}}, { {6, 8, 2},  {5, -2, -15},  {16, 9, 7}}, { {6, 8, 7},  {5, -2, -10},  {16, 9, 12}}, { {6, 9, 2},  {5, -1, -15},  {16, 10, 7}}, { {6, 9, 3},  {5, -1, -14},  {16, 10, 8}}, { {6, 9, 7},  {5, -1, -10},  {16, 10, 12}}, { {6, 9, 8},  {5, -1, -9},  {16, 10, 13}}, { {7, 1, 3},  {6, -9, -14},  {17, 2, 8}}, { {7, 1, 4},  {6, -9, -13},  {17, 2, 9}}, { {7, 1, 5},  {6, -9, -12},  {17, 2, 10}}, { {7, 1, 9},  {6, -9, -8},  {17, 2, 14}}, { {7, 2, 4},  {6, -8, -13},  {17, 3, 9}}, { {7, 2, 5},  {6, -8, -12},  {17, 3, 10}}, { {7, 2, 8},  {6, -8, -9},  {17, 3, 13}}, { {7, 3, 5},  {6, -7, -12},  {17, 4, 10}}, { {7, 3, 8},  {6, -7, -9},  {17, 4, 13}}, { {7, 3, 9},  {6, -7, -8},  {17, 4, 14}}, { {7, 4, 3},  {6, -6, -14},  {17, 5, 8}}, { {7, 4, 8},  {6, -6, -9},  {17, 5, 13}}, { {7, 4, 9},  {6, -6, -8},  {17, 5, 14}}, { {7, 8, 5},  {6, -2, -12},  {17, 9, 10}}, { {7, 9, 3},  {6, -1, -14},  {17, 10, 8}}, { {7, 9, 8},  {6, -1, -9},  {17, 10, 13}}, { {8, 1, 4},  {7, -9, -13},  {18, 2, 9}}, { {8, 1, 5},  {7, -9, -12},  {18, 2, 10}}, { {8, 1, 6},  {7, -9, -11},  {18, 2, 11}}, { {8, 1, 9},  {7, -9, -8},  {18, 2, 14}}, { {8, 2, 1},  {7, -8, -16},  {18, 3, 6}}, { {8, 2, 4},  {7, -8, -13},  {18, 3, 9}}, { {8, 2, 5},  {7, -8, -12},  {18, 3, 10}}, { {8, 2, 6},  {7, -8, -11},  {18, 3, 11}}, { {8, 3, 1},  {7, -7, -16},  {18, 4, 6}}, { {8, 3, 5},  {7, -7, -12},  {18, 4, 10}}, { {8, 3, 6},  {7, -7, -11},  {18, 4, 11}}, { {8, 3, 9},  {7, -7, -8},  {18, 4, 14}}, { {8, 4, 1},  {7, -6, -16},  {18, 5, 6}}, { {8, 4, 6},  {7, -6, -11},  {18, 5, 11}}, { {8, 4, 9},  {7, -6, -8},  {18, 5, 14}}, { {8, 5, 4},  {7, -5, -13},  {18, 6, 9}}, { {8, 5, 9},  {7, -5, -8},  {18, 6, 14}}, { {8, 9, 1},  {7, -1, -16},  {18, 10, 6}}, { {8, 9, 6},  {7, -1, -11},  {18, 10, 11}}, { {9, 1, 5},  {8, -9, -12},  {19, 2, 10}}, { {9, 1, 6},  {8, -9, -11},  {19, 2, 11}}, { {9, 1, 7},  {8, -9, -10},  {19, 2, 12}}, { {9, 2, 1},  {8, -8, -16},  {19, 3, 6}}, { {9, 2, 5},  {8, -8, -12},  {19, 3, 10}}, { {9, 2, 6},  {8, -8, -11},  {19, 3, 11}}, { {9, 2, 7},  {8, -8, -10},  {19, 3, 12}}, { {9, 3, 1},  {8, -7, -16},  {19, 4, 6}}, { {9, 3, 2},  {8, -7, -15},  {19, 4, 7}}, { {9, 3, 5},  {8, -7, -12},  {19, 4, 10}}, { {9, 3, 6},  {8, -7, -11},  {19, 4, 11}}, { {9, 3, 7},  {8, -7, -10},  {19, 4, 12}}, { {9, 4, 1},  {8, -6, -16},  {19, 5, 6}}, { {9, 4, 2},  {8, -6, -15},  {19, 5, 7}}, { {9, 4, 6},  {8, -6, -11},  {19, 5, 11}}, { {9, 4, 7},  {8, -6, -10},  {19, 5, 12}}, { {9, 5, 2},  {8, -5, -15},  {19, 6, 7}}, { {9, 5, 7},  {8, -5, -10},  {19, 6, 12}}, { {9, 6, 5},  {8, -4, -12},  {19, 7, 10}}
```

Now I want to find coordinates of centroid, orthocenter and center of out circle the list of triangles. With each triangle, e.g with center of out circle, I tried

```
a = {1, 3, 4};
b = {20, 14, 2};
c = {9, 10, -3};
t = {x, y, z};
u = b - a;
v = c - a;
n = Cross[u, v];
k = t - a;
w = k.n;
Reduce[{SquaredEuclideanDistance[a, t] == 
   SquaredEuclideanDistance[b, t], 
  SquaredEuclideanDistance[a, t] == SquaredEuclideanDistance[c, t], 
  w == 0}, {x, y, z}, Reals]
```

and with orthocenter, I tried

```
a = {1, 3, 4};
b = {20, 14, 2};
c = {9, 10, -3};
h = {x1, y1, z1};
u = b - a;
v = c - a;
k = h - a;
n = Cross[u, v];
w = k.n;
Reduce[{(h - a). (c - b) == 0, (h - b).(c - a) == 0, w == 0}, {x1, y1, z1}, Reals]
```

And with centroid, I tried, `(a + b + c)/3`.

I want to out put has the form 
{{1, 3, 4},  {20, 14, 2},  {9, 10, -3}, {coordinates of centroid},{coordinates of orthocenter},{coordinates of center of out circle} }

I saw http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/203101-How-Can-I-Make-A-Triangle-With-Integer and wrote a program in *Maple*. I got all results
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Your "list of vertices of triangles" should use braces and not brackets; otherwise, it's not a valid list.

Comment: @J.M. Edited now.

Comment: So, all your triangles are in 3D?

Comment: @J.M. Yes. All my triangles are in 3D.

Comment: By "outcircle", you mean the *circumcircle*, right?

Comment: Yes. you are right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43116/discussion-between-toandhsp-and-j-m).

Answer (score 4):

I am certain there are better ways. In the following the black point is the orthocentre, the red point is the centroid and the green point the circumcentre.

```
oc[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Module[{pt = {a, b, c}, s1 = b - a, s2 = c - b, s3 = a - c, pr, 
   lines},
  pr = MapThread[#1 + 
      Norm[#2[[3]]] Cos[
        VectorAngle[#2[[1]], -#2[[3]]]] Normalize[#2[[1]]] &, {{a, b, 
      c}, Table[RotateLeft[{s1, s2, s3}, j], {j, 0, 2}]}];
  lines = 
   MapThread[InfiniteLine[{#1, #2}] &, {pr, RotateRight[pt, 1]}];
  {lines, RegionIntersection[lines[[{1, 2}]]]}
  ]
cc[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Module[{pt = {a, b, c}, s1 = b - a, s2 = c - b, s3 = c - a, nu, de},
  nu = (s3.s3) Cross[Cross[s1, s3], s1] + (s1.s1) Cross[s3, 
      Cross[s1, s3]];
  de = Cross[s1, s3];
  a + nu/(2 de.de)
  ]
cn[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{pt = {a, b, c}, bis, lines},
  bis = (#1 + #2)/2 & @@@ Partition[pt, 2, 1, 1];
  lines = MapThread[Line[{#1, #2}] &, {bis, RotateRight[pt]}];
  {lines, RegionIntersection[lines[[{1, 2}]]]}
  ]
circle[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{pt = {a, b, c}, ccn = cc[a, b, c], i, j},
  i = a - ccn;
  j = Normalize@Cross[Cross[i, b - ccn], i];
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[ccn + Cos[t] i + Sqrt[i.i] Sin[t] j], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

Visualizing:

```
vis[a_, b_, c_] := 
 Module[{ort = oc[a, b, c], p3 = Point[cc[a, b, c]], 
   cnt = cn[a, b, c], l1, l2, p1, p2, circ = circle[a, b, c]},
  {l1, p1} = ort;
  {l2, p2} = cnt;
  Show[Graphics3D[{Polygon[{a, b, c}], Black , l1, PointSize[0.04], 
     p1, Red, l2, p2, Green, p3, Purple, Thick, 
     Line[{p1[[1]], p2[[1, 1]], p3[[1]]}]}], circ]]
```

Examples:

```
DynamicModule[{pts = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]}, 
 Dynamic[Column[{vis @@ pts, 
    Button["Random triangle", pts = RandomReal[1, {3, 3}]]}, 
   Frame -> True]]]
```

[image]